# Forgotten Apple ID password and not receiving password reset email

Tags: apple-id

I have attempted on several occasions to request a reset for my forgotten password but I've never received the password reset email from Apple. It is not in my junk mail either.

How can I go about resetting my password to access my account? I do not want to have to get another email address. Do I need to contact Apple?

Comment: Have you tried using the security questions to recover your password? Do you have a rescue email address listed for the Apple ID?